# Which is more efficient memory wise: static functions, or functions of an object that is deleted right away?

Tags: c++, function

The question as what the title says, static functions? or functions of an object that is deleted right away?

I know that in a real situation the difference is completely unnoticable but i would still like to know which is more efficient in saving memory. I really don't mind the overhead given by the "new" and "delete" command.

```
MyClass::staticFunction();
```

or...

```
myObject = new MyClass;
myObject->normalFunction();
delete myObject;
```

edit: the second code might as well be `MyClass().normalFunction();` silly...

there are a few things to consider here;

1. there will only be one instance of the myObject, and it is only used ONCE in the application.
2. after usage, it is deleted right away because it is not needed.
3. one would ask, why is this even in a class? why not just put the function where it is used with temporary variables? the answer is encapsulation and readability. i do believe static functions use the same resources as global functions since in fact, they really are global functions that enjoy class scope. the only reason i have to put it in it's own class is to make my code more readable, and encapsulation.

Comment: Why are you worrying about this? Have your ***proved*** that it matter in the instance before you? If not do the *right thing* and stop worrying about the fast thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it stands, none of this makes any sense. The real solution would be to provide a *free* function (a function at namespace scope), because ***this is what free functions are there for***.

Oh, and since you asked: If calling this one single function has noticeable overhead in your code, then you will only find out about it through careful profiling. Profiling is also what would answer your question which way is faster.
But first make sure your code is easy to read and well maintainable. Optimizing this then will be much easier than fixing prematurely micro-"optimized" code. The only early optimizations you should employ are those that result in optimal data structures and algorithms.

(Note that `new` and `delete` will very likely have far greater overhead than what the function actually *does*, let alone calling it.)

Comment: *free function*, got it. Just to add, I AM NOT WRITING ANY CODE. I just wanted to know about it before doing anything. and also, i did mention that i don't mind the overhead given by new and delete. since it may as well just be MyClass().normalFunction() as @sehe has said.

Answer (score 4):

> in fact, they really are global functions that enjoy class scope

I think that is spot on.

It doesn't make much of a difference. However, the following would make a *lot* more sense:

```
{
    MyClass myObject;
    myObject.normalFunction();
}
```

Or even,

```
MyClass().normalFunction();
```

Why would you bother creating a heap-allocated instance of an object that doesn't even matter?

Comment: Indeed, heap-allocation is unnecessary, unless the object itself with its members is huge.

Answer (score 1):

We can't say for certain without trying it on a specific platform (or knowing the details of that platform), but we can probably say that the static one will not be slower than the one with new & delete.

Answer (score 0):

There is no overhead to calling *non-virtual* member function versus class static function versus a free function since binding is resolved at compile-time. The only difference is that member functions get one extra argument for `this` pointer, but with static and free function you have to pass the object somehow, so it's the same.

Comment: You contradict yourself. Passing `this` *is* overhead :)

Comment: While I completely agree with your point in general, I do not think that the OP was going to pass the object. Actually, *if* he passes the object and stores data in its non-static members it will add a runtime overhead of using this members.

Comment: You don't have to pass the object if there are no data members, so a static function is more efficient in that case (let alone the creation of the temporary pointless empty object that still must be of non-zero size).

Comment: On the other hand, the question was what is more efficient *memory wise*…

Comment: "binding is resolved at compile-time", surprisingly that just answered everything. so I'm assuming in modern compilers it technically does no difference. thank you for your answer, straight to the point.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is complex enough that you think it needs to be in its own class, then that suggests multiple methods and state stored in the object. You're asking to compare that to using multiple functions, and by implication state passed as arguments. If there's a lot of shared state between the methods, using an object is reasonable. If there's not, using multiple functions is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

For scoping you may just prefer using namespace.

On the other hand, since you're asking for **memory** efficience, I can see one reason why you may prefer the object. If you're going to have a consider amount of memory allocated, encapsulating it in the object members sounds like a way to free them afterwards.